# Custom WS-Policy with Spring-WS

Tags: spring, web-services, soap, spring-ws

I am using Spring-WS to provide services and generate WSDL. I want to mention in generated WSDL that some SOAP headers are required. Header should look like:

```
<soapenv:Header>
     <my:System>ABC</my:System>
</soapenv:Header>
```

Being said I need to provide some WS-Policy, what headers are provided. How can I tell Spring to create such a policy?

Comment: I admit it is a long time ago. Did you solve it?